# Hit enter automatically when running apt-get install <package> prompts a dialog boxes

Tags: shell, linux-mint, shell-script, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running command `apt-get install -y <package>`. It overcomes confirmation like

> Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

But in the process of updating, I got a popup which asks to hit enter in that popup box to continue. How can I hit enter while popup occurs in the middle running `apt-get install -y <package>` command in shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Search for apt-get and "non-interactive" or "unattended"

You can find an answer here:

https://serverfault.com/q/227190